# Need to create tuples as dictionary keys from a csv in the form (year, state_po, candidate) = candidatevotes without pandas

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

Here are some rows of the csv. I have looked over several stackexchange questions, and other resources but have not been able to come up with a clear solution. I converted my csv into a dictionary using DictReader. I am not sure how to turn the specific columns into a tuple key. I also need to filter for the year 2020. I am not sure how to do that without pandas either.

```
"year","state","state_po","county_name","county_fips","office","candidate","party","candidatevotes","totalvotes","version","mode"
2000,"ALABAMA","AL","AUTAUGA","1001","PRESIDENT","AL GORE","DEMOCRAT",4942,17208,20191203,"TOTAL"
2000,"ALABAMA","AL","AUTAUGA","1001","PRESIDENT","GEORGE W. BUSH","REPUBLICAN",11993,17208,20191203,"TOTAL"
2000,"ALABAMA","AL","AUTAUGA","1001","PRESIDENT","RALPH NADER","GREEN",160,17208,20191203,"TOTAL"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionary comprehension is probably the most Pythonic way.

```py
import csv
with open('csv') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    data = {(i['year'], i['state_po'], i['candidate']): i['candidatevotes'] for i in reader}
```

After which `data` is:

```py
{('2000', 'AL', 'AL GORE'): '4942',
 ('2000', 'AL', 'GEORGE W. BUSH'): '11993',
 ('2000', 'AL', 'RALPH NADER'): '160'}
```